# selectively ignoring mouse events in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, events, mouse, filtering

I am writing an application that gets input from 3 mice. 2 of the mice are used for gestures and their input is handled separately, the 3rd should function as normal.
I have successfully installed an eventfilter (see below) that runs my own mouse-processing code (*processMouse()*).

However, when trying to get the filter to ignore the events from certain mice (determined by the boolean return value of *processMouse()*), nothing gets ignored.

I have tried using the normal true/false return values, resetting the event to a "None" event, calling it's ignore function, but the mouse still keeps moving even when I tell it to ignore the event.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event){
    if ((event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove) ||
        (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)){
        if (configured){
            if (!processMouse()){
                //event->ignore();
                //event = new QEvent(QEvent::None);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

How can I *selectively* ignore MouseMove events from an eventfilter?

Comment: Mouse movement isn't handled by Qt, it's handled by your window manager. The mouseMove event is just a signal from the window manager to Qt, you can't cancel it from within your app (without knowing a lot about your window manager & environment)

Comment: Assigning something to event doesn't alter the original event (nor its processing) at all. It just changes the value of your local pointer variable, now pointing to the newly created event (which will be lost) instead of the one actually processed. That assignment is local to your method, it won't get noticed anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'm now trying to work my way around it by using the return value of my processMouse function to determine whether or not the position of the cursor should be set back. it probably won't be as pretty as drawing and implementing a new one, but it should work for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was eventually solved by using a 3rd party library named "ManyMouse", which receives each mouse's input separately.